# PHP global path setting

Tags: php, url, path, global

I have this setting.

```
 root dir| 
       index.php
       config.php
       file.php  |
                 |
                 |scripts|a.js
                 |
                 |account
                         |index.php
                         |         |
                         |member   |index.php
```

- Now, I've included index.php of member dir into index.php of account dir. Also , the account index.php includes the config.php which contains,

  ```
  define( 'PATH', (__DIR__) );
  ```

Now , for all includes in account index.php I use,

```
require_once( PATH . '\file.php' );
```

and is working properly. But when I try to add the path for script src such as,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php '.PATH.'scripts/livevalidation.js ?>"></script>
```

I get an error, so how can i include the a.js in scripts folder into index.php of account using the globally defined path.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PHP "__DIR__" and "__FILE__" are absolute to the server. You shouldn't need to use either for your script.

```
<script src="/scripts/livevalidation.js"></script>
```

Also, your PHP looks like it has some syntax errors, this would be correct (although still wouldn't work:

```
<script src="<?php echo PATH.'/scripts/livevalidation.js'; ?>"></script>
```

Comment: Since I'm testing locally I get this in script src         <script type="text/javascript" src="E:\public_html\demoscripts/livevalidation.js"></script>  So how can i make it to refer the script file properly

Comment: @Ajay, I would just use the first code example I used, just using "/scripts/" since that is relative to the webroot (i.e. / is yoursite.com/, /scripts/ is yoursite.com/scripts/). Relative to the domain

Comment: Also, as you're on a Windows server, your server paths will have "\" but the web paths need "/"

Comment: Hi, the problem is i'm referring the scripts folder from root/account/index.php and i don't want to use ../

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a `print` or `echo` statement in the PHP statement in your `script` tag. You're also placing the concatination periods in the wrong place. On top of that, however, the JavaScript you're trying to include doesn't need to be in the PHP statement.

All that said, the final line should read like the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo PATH ?>scripts/livevalidation.js"></script>
```

On top of that, however, I don't think the above will work as you expect. `__DIR__` outputs a server-side filesystem path, which wouldn't make sense when importing JavaScript over HTTP. I'd recommend something more along the lines of the following:

```
<?php define('URL_ROOT', '/'); ?>

<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo URL_ROOT ?>scripts/livevalidation.js"></script>
```

In the above example `URL_ROOT` would point an absolute URL under which your static media (CSS, JavaScript, and so on) is served.